# How to convert a String Array to a Long Array in a Java8 one-liner?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, long-integer

I'm solving the "Count Triplets" problem on HackerRank.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps
It says that I must work with an array, although HC converts it to a List.
I want to convert in into an array instead of a list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        String[] nr = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(nr[0]);

        long r = Long.parseLong(nr[1]);

        **List<Long> arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Long::parseLong)
                .collect(toList());**

        long ans = countTriplets(arr, r);

        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(ans));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        bufferedReader.close();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it as follows:

```
Long[] arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Long::parseLong)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

## Update:

Courtesy [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298831/how-to-convert-a-string-array-to-a-long-array-in-a-java8-one-liner/63298923#comment111936073_63298923)

There is no need to collect into a `List` as shown above. You can do it simply as

```
Long[] arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .map(Long::parseLong)
                .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

**Alternatively,**

```
long[] arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                .mapToLong(Long::parseLong) 
                .toArray()
```

Comment: There is no need to collect into a `List` when you want an array. Instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList()) .toArray(Long[]::new)` just invoke `.toArray(Long[]::new)` directly on the Stream. Or use `.mapToLong(Long::parseLong) .toArray()` to get a `long[]` array.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger for always providing valuable suggestions. I've updated the answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toArray(Long[]::new)` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

```
Long[] arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
                   .map(Long::parseLong)
                   .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do this

```
Arrays.stream(strArray).map(Long::valueOf).toArray(Long[]::new)
```